# Byte-Pairing for data compression

Tags: algorithm, compression

Question about Byte-Pairing for data compression. If byte pairing converts two byte values to a single byte value, splitting the file in half, then taking a gig file and recusing it 16 times shrinks it to 62,500,000. My question is, is byte-pairing really efficient? Is the creation of a 5,000,000 iteration loop, to be conservative, efficient? I would like some feed back on and some incisive opinions please.

---

Dave, what I read was:
"The US patent office no longer grants patents on perpetual motion machines, but has recently granted at least two patents on a mathematically impossible process: compression of truly random data."
I was not inferring the Patent Office was actually considering what I am inquiring about.    I was merely commenting on the notion of a "mathematically impossible process." If someone has, in some way created a method of having a "single" data byte as a placeholder of  8 individual bytes of data, that would be a consideration for a patent.   Now,  about the  mathematically impossibility of an 8 to 1 compression method, it is not so much a mathematically impossibility, but a series of rules and conditions that can be created.  As long as there is the rule of 8 or 16 bit representation of  storing data on a medium, there are ways to manipulate data that mirrors current methods, or creation by a new way of thinking.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll manage to trim the length of your data by 50% with each pass...

Comment: http://gailly.net/05533051.html is a good read for some impossible compression algorithms.

Comment: If an innovative algorithm can shrink 16 "Truly Random" byte chunks in to a single byte, from what I read is a consideration for a (possible)-patent.

Comment: @user1669533: No, it is *mathematically impossible* to perform such shrinking. The fact that it is under consideration for a patent just reflects badly on the US patent office (which is the point of the entire link).

Comment: @user1669533: This doesn't have anything to do with innovation or creativity. There is no way to represent *any* 8 bytes of data as a single byte of data. Mathematical impossibility is exactly the right term.

Comment: So, there is no way in creating a dictionary table that will take a series of data [x,y,z,r,u, k,..] and have a rule set defining if this occurs set output to [b]?

Comment: The problem is not creating a dictionary table or a rule set -- internal to the compressor, you can do anything you want.  The problem is coming up with an output encoding that is smaller than the input file for all input files...

Comment: ... and again, if you want to argue specifics, you should probably provide some.

Answer (score 5):

In general, "recursive compression" as you have described it is a mirage:  compression doesn't actually work that way.

First, you should realize that all compression algorithms have the potential to expand the input file instead of compressing it.  You can demonstrate this by a simple counting argument:  note that the compressed version of any file must be different from the compressed version of any other file (or you will not be able to decompress that file properly).  Also, for any file size `N`, there is a fixed number of possible files of size `<=N`.  If any files of size `> N` are compressible to size `<= N`, then an equal number of files of size `<= N` must expand to size `>N` when "compressed".

Second, "truly random" files are uncompressible.  Compression works because the compression algorithm expects to receive files with certain kinds of predictable regularities.  However, "truly random" files are by definition unpredictable:  every random file is as likely as every other random file of the same length, so they don't compress.

Effectively, you have a model which treats some files as more likely than others; to compress such files, you want to choose shorter output files for the input files which are more likely.  [Information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) tells us the most efficient way to compress files is to assign each input file of probability `P` an output file of length `~ log2(1/P)` bits.  This means that, ideally, every *output* file of a given length has roughly *equal probability*, just like "truly random" files.

Among completely random files of a given length, each has probability `(0.5)^(#original bits)`.  The optimal length from above is `~ log2(1/ 0.5^(#original bits) ) = (#original bits)` -- which is to say, the original length is the best you can do.

Because the output of a good compression algorithm is nearly random, re-compressing the compressed file will get you little to no gain.  Any further improvements are effectively "leakage" due to suboptimal modeling and encoding;  also, compression algorithms tend to scramble any regularity they don't take advantage of, making further compression of such "leakage" more difficult.

---

For a much longer exposition on this topic, with many examples of failed propositions of this type, see the [comp.compression FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/part1/section-8.html).  Claims of "recursive compression" feature prominently.

Comment: "Second, "truly random" files are uncompressible" could you expand further - I don't understand this...

Comment: Robbie, when I first read about byte pair compression I became curious about the amount of "raw" data the algorithm has to trough through.  A Two-to-One  task will be a monstrous loop to cycle through, granted if  a 1gig file is being read in, then that will require a large loop count. My question was; is byte pairing an efficient method. If you are reading two bytes at a time, that would be a slow and unwanted process. Maybe, if threading was involved it would make it more efficient.  I am just doing research on different methods of compression.

Comment: I have added a section on "truly random=uncompressible".  @user1669533, if you want people to answer questions specific to byte pair compression, you will need to provide some kind of description or reference.  But no matter the description, it cannot compress *all* files, and claims that it can compress recursively are a red flag for such.

Comment: @user1669533 Why are you asking if it's going to be efficent or not, if you got something that works who cares about efficiency, if it works then its already something that hasn't been done before and you can patent it and make a good profit. But if you don't know what you're doing, you might as well post it here on SO and let the pros take a look at what you got to work with.